# swift Notification center use of Undeclared Type Name Error

Tags: ios, swift

I've run into the most frustrating bug.
I'm setting up Notifications in my application and am using swift 4.2. Im using the new syntax. My popupController I've set is up as follows

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .saveFoodGroup, object: self)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i've created a `NotificationCenterExtension.swift` file with the name in it:

```
extension Notification.Name {
static let saveFoodGroup = Notification.Name(rawValue: "saveFoodGroup")
}
```

In my controller I set the observer up inside the `.viewDidLoad()`as follows :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  forName: .saveFoodGroup,
  object: nil,
  queue: OperationQueue.main ) {
     (notification) in
         let groupPopUp = notification.object as! ScalePopUpController
         print(groupPopUp)
         self.foodGroup = groupPopUp.textInput as? String
   }
```

But on runtime I keep getting this error:

```
unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7fb9c7e23ef0'
```

After some searching i've discovered that this is an old ObjC error when the #selectors are not set properly.
But since I'm using the new syntax this should not be an issue.
A last clue: When I hover over the `.saveFoodGroup` argument in my `NotificatioCenter.default.post(name: .saveFoodGroup`) call; I get this cryptic hint; `expression produced error: error:`

> /var/folders/xj/f18tylg51kl33z6c6p2vh34r0000gn/T/expr15-a14342..swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'Name'`

Can anybody please tell me what is going on?

**Full error message:**

```
2018-12-04 20:17:28.780056+0100 unFatMobile[47399:4108185] -[unFatMobile.ScalePopUpController onBtPRew:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9c7e23ef0
2018-12-04 20:17:28.787522+0100 unFatMobile[47399:4108185] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[unFatMobile.ScalePopUpController onBtPRew:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb9c7e23ef0'

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c6b91bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a6d3735 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c6d7f44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   UIKitCore                           0x000000010f091b4a -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c6bded6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c6bfda8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
6   UIKitCore                           0x000000010f064ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
7   UIKitCore                           0x000000010eaa00bd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010eaa03da -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010ea9f31e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f0a00a4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
11  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f0a17a0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4080
12  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f07f394 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
13  UIKit                               0x0000000127f0b183 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 85
14  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f1545a9 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3054
15  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f1571cb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5948
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c61e721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c61df93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c61863f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c617e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
20  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001147d41dd GSEventRunModal + 62
21  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f06381d UIApplicationMain + 140
22  unFatMobile                         0x0000000109d56f47 main + 71
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010db52575 start + 1
)
```

Comment: Full error message? To know the class and the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place ( may be button action)   you post the notification from

> -[unFatMobile.ScalePopUpController onBtPRew:]

has an action method named `onBtPRew` that you linked it to Ib , then removed it , here the notification implementation ( selector && @objc ) has no relation to this crash and the new inline callback is working

`Note :` this occurs also when you copy elements inside IB , the attached actions copied with them , so make sure to disconnect unrelated actions

Comment: Ooh wauw thanks!!!! :) :) , all this time I thought it was the Notification Center .....

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer also , as that time it'll be the notification center

Comment: Thanks, It all works now!! A "mind" high-five from Amsterdam is incoming!

Comment: @ArneOldenhave The way to express thanks on Stack Overflow is to _accept_ the answer (click the checkmark to the left of the answer so that it is filled).